# eXistDB performance issues - how to improve?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I'm here to ask if I'm configuring eXist DB wrong or if it's simply unable to cope with the amount of data I need to store and query in eXist.

I'm running eXist 4.3.1 stable on Ubuntu 18 on a machine with a Quad-Core i5 with 16GB RAM whereby I've allocated 8GB to eXist. I configured new range indexes on all values I'm interested in querying. The indexes work, I can test them with simple queries and in Monex they show up as full optimized using the new range index.

Right now I'm testing with 110434 XML Files with sizes between 20kb to 3mb. I'm using XML Namespaces and optimized queries (I read https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/tuning) but still I observe insanely long exectuion times.

This query:

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace oai = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/";

for $x in collection("/db/apps/ddb/data")
return $x//oai:identifier
```

takes 0.5 Seconds to execute (great!). If I use a `contains` predicate test (which is using a new range index), like so:

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace oai = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/";

for $x in collection("/db/apps/ddb/data")
return $x//oai:identifier[contains(., 'mainz')]
```

the execution time longer than 5 Minutes, which is by no means acceptable.

I attached an image which shows the long exection times and the index usage:
[image]

It would be great if someone who works with large Datasets in eXist could **comment on the performance of eXist** or if someone could **comment on my Index configuration** and/or **query writing**.

Thanks!

Comment: Only assumptions. Use matches() instead of contains. lets see is it ok! : https://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/11206045/

Comment: Wow, that sped up the exectution insane! Thanks, I will look into the articel you linked. So it's really just a query problem after all?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Amrendra Kumar's tip, and to quote the docs you already mentioned:

> Consider an n-gram index for exact substring queries on longer text
>   sequences

Xquery string operations, e.g those that process reg-ex require full-text processing, regardless of the fact that you have created a new-range index or not. You can either substitute these expressions with another more performant expression, matches () instead of contains() or use another index n-gram or full-text instead of new-range.

When you have defined multiple indexes on the same node. You can specify which index should be used by using the appropriate xQuery expressions,  such as ft:query. This can greatly improve performance, since the default query optimizer is bound to get it wrong every now and then.

Without adding some sample data and the collection.xconf it is, however, impossible to comment on your index configuration. Your needs don't sound particularly outlandish for exist-db, but without knowing more about concurrent users, update frequency etc, I can't offer more than a general remarks like this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm re-indexing right now with a newly configured n-gram index and I'll let you know how it goes next week (and accept your answer)